# How to select alphanumeric characters using regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am fairly new to regexp_substr in oracle. I want extract just alphanumeric character from the string below. I have used below query but it doesn't seems to be working as expected.

```
select 
    regexp_substr('Save up to 10% on National Brands and 20% on Quill Brand Laser Toner','[[:alnum:]]+') string 
from dual;
```

I want the output to be look like this

> Save up to 10 on National Brands and 20 on Quill Brand Laser Toner

or

> Saveupto10onNationalBrandsand20onQuillBrandLaserToner

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: As @benji points out below, what you're actually looking to do is to *replace* those non-alphanumeric characters with nothing - so you'll want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` rather than `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `regexp_replace`

```
select 
    regexp_replace('Save up to 10% on National Brands and 20% on Quill Brand Laser Toner',
                 '[^[:alnum:]]', '') string from dual;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23394/11)

Comment: You can actually omit the third parameter `''` from that `REGEXP_REPLACE()` as Oracle will use NULL by default.